# How to get rid of vignetting in Raspberry-Pi camera pictures?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am working on a project which requires taking a number of pictures from a raspberry-pi camera from a drone. There seems to cyan vignetting in most of the output pictures from pi camera. I searched different forums and help available online on cyan vignetting is quite limited. I tried enabling still stats to get rid of vignetting (mentioned on one of the forums), and it worked well. However, still stats recalculates color balance of images and messes it up (I need to have fixed color balance settings for all images in this project).

I need some suggestions on how can I completely get rid of all vignetting in output images while keeping constant color balance for all images.

The image below shows an example of vignetting

[image]

The image on left is a vignetted picture and the corresponding correct pic is on the right. Note that vignetting can occur in one channel of an image (e.g. green) where as the other channels can be fine.

Are there any specific settings in the raspberry pi that can get rig of vignetting other than still stats?

Comment: If you need fixed colour balance, why not set it to `off` or `sunny` instead of `auto`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am not setting the color balance to auto. I used fixed values for blue and red gain for every picture (and camera.awb_mode = 'off') to ensure a fixed color balance. The problem is with vignetting.

Comment: Maybe some sample images would help - showing the problem and how it should look when corrected and what processing you applied.

Comment: I have edited the question to include extra information.

Comment: Have a look at [lensfunpy](https://github.com/letmaik/lensfunpy), a python wrapper for [lensfun](http://lensfun.sourceforge.net/). It uses `OpenCV` or `Scipy` to try and correct for things like this (distortion, fish-eyeing, and vignetting). If it doesn't have the raspi camera in it's database then you can [do the calibration yourself](http://wilson.bronger.org/lens_calibration_tutorial/#id3).